# Render run twice times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I've a list of countries which i would like show some info related to the country. I run a loop in order to show the info for each country. I've created a component for a country.

```
const CountryCard = ({ info }) => {
  const { country, infoForLastDate, path } = info
  return (
    <Card >
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2" >
          {country.name}
        </Typography>
        <Flag oneToOne={country.oneToOne} fourToThree={country.fourToThree} />
        <Typography variant="body2" >
          Confirmed: {infoForLastDate.confirmed}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
          Recovered: {infoForLastDate.recovered}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
        Deaths: {infoForLastDate.deaths}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Link href={path}>
          See more
        </Link>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default CountryCard
```

Also, I've created another component to show the flag related to the country.

```
import React from 'react'
import { imageUrlFor } from '../lib/image-url'

const Flag = ({ oneToOne, fourToThree }) => {
  const  url = imageUrlFor(oneToOne.asset._id)

  return (
    <img src={url} />
  )
}

export default Flag
```

I get the error `TypeError: oneToOne is null`

i don't know why it is like the flags render twice times. when I debugged, first time  `oneToOne` property has a value, but at the end is run again and is `null`

Why is it happens?

Edit: Add CountryList component:

```
const CountryList = ({list}) => {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      { list.length > 1 && list.map(country => {
        const countryWithPath = {
          ...country,
          path: `/country/${country.country.name.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-').replace('*', '')}`
        }
        return (
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} key={country._id} >
            <CountryCard info={countryWithPath} />
          </Grid>)
      })
      }
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default CountryList
```

Comment: How do you pass `info` to `<CountryCard />` component? Probably you missing out `oneToOne` from there - in `country`.

Comment: pls add component that uses <CountreyCard />

Comment: Added. The list comes from StaticQuery  component (provided for gatsby)

Comment: By the way, if you have just one country, your component will not render, because your condition now is:  `{ list.length > 1 ...} `  You could fix that, by simply using `{ list.length && ....  } ` as in JavaScript 0 translates to `false` and any other number is equal to `true`

Comment: you can `log(list)` before  `{ list.length > 1 && list.map(country =>`  to see if your array have the oneToOne key   in every country   i think maybe in doesn't exist for the second country in the list

Comment: Enchew good point, thanks!

Rkv88-Kanyan you're right. I've checked the list and one country doesn't have the asset for the flags.

But... why does react try to render a second time?